# Creating defects in QC from Jenkins when build fails

Tags: jenkins, hp-quality-center

I'm running Jenkins in Linux and I want to raise defects in QC when the build fails. What's the easiest way to do that?

Comment: [this](http://antagonisticpleiotropy.blogspot.ca/2014/02/jenkins-hps-alm-quality-center-qc-rest.html) might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QC has a REST API that you can use, actually with anything that talks via HTTP, e.g.

```
curl -b qc_cookies -c qc_cookies -u <USERNAME:PASSWORD> http://<QC_SERVER:PORT>/qcbin/authentication-point/authenticate

curl -b qc_cookies -c qc_cookies -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X POST -d @<QC_DEFECT_PAYLOAD.xml> http://<QC_SERVER:PORT>/qcbin/rest/domains/<DOMAIN>/projects/<PROJECT>/defects

curl -b qc_cookies -c qc_cookies http://<QC_SERVER:PORT>/qcbin/authentication-point/logout
```

More details on how to use it with Jenkins can be found at   http://antagonisticpleiotropy.blogspot.com.au/2014/02/jenkins-hps-alm-quality-center-qc-rest.html

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. Edit and post relevant content in your post